# Android - communicating with the built-in GSM module using AT commands

Tags: java, android, shell, at-command

I'm trying to send AT commands to the GSM module of my phone with an Android application. However, I can't seem to be getting a response, only very rarely, because when reading back the result, the `cat` command doesn't read anything.

My code:

```
Process p = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        try {
            Log.i("APP","reading");
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
            InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
            int len = 0;
            int tries = 10;
            byte[] buff = new byte[4096];
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            os.writeBytes("pkill -9 -f cat\necho -e \"ATI\\r\" > dev/smd0 && cat dev/smd0\n");
            while (is.available() <= 0 && tries > 0) {
                try {
                    Log.e("APP","unsuccessful");
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    tries--;
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
            while (tries > 0 && is.available() > 0) {
                len = is.read(buff);
                if (len <= 0) break;
                String seg = new String(buff, 0, len);
                Log.i("APP", seg);
                sb.append(seg);
            }
            os.writeBytes("exit\n");
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            is.close();
            p.getErrorStream().close();
            Toast.makeText(this, sb.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Example of output:

http://pastebin.com/y7T2cGpL

Answer (score 0):

Opening and closing the modem device in between sending the command and reading the response like that might be troublesome. You could instead try to use the [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/) program which is designed to do AT command communication from the command line (and will only open the modem device once while running).

Then you would change your code to

- Create a file `input.txt` which contains the commands you want to run (e.g. `ATI`) with plain `\n` line endings.
- Execute `atinout inout.txt /dev/smd0 output.txt`
- Read the `output.txt` file.

Unfortunately compiling atinout for android is not something I have tried myself and can give any help on, but I have seen other people refering to it done.

---

Also note that killing `cat` like that is a bit dangerous; you risk killing cat instances started by other scripts that just happen to run at the same time...